# An object being added to a list is not being stored in a database

Tags: c#, database, list, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am developing an C# MVC 4 internet application and I have a question about adding an item to a list.

Here is my class code:

```
public class MapLocationCompany
{
    public MapLocationCompany()
    {
        MapLocationList = new List<MapLocation>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<MapLocation> MapLocationList { get; set; }
}

public class MapLocationCompanyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MapLocationCompany> MapLocationCompanies { get; set; }
}
```

I am creating a `MapLocation` object to add to the `MapLocationList` in the `MapLocationCompany` class.

Here is my code:

```
private MapLocationCompanyContext mlcc = new MapLocationCompanyContext();

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int id, MapLocation maplocation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MapLocationCompany mapLocationCompany = new MapLocationCompany();
        mapLocationCompany = cs.getMapLocationCompany(id);
        mapLocationCompany.MapLocationList.Add(maplocation);
        mlcc.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("MapLocations", "Company", new { id = id });
    }

    return View(maplocation);
}
```

Here is the `cs.getMapLocationCompany` function that is in a different class

```
public MapLocationCompany getMapLocationCompany(int id)
{
    return db.MapLocationCompanies.Where(c => c.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The db is a `MapLocationCompanyContext` object.

The `maplocation` object in the `Create` function is not being stored in the database.

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Can I please have some help to add the MapLocation object to the list using the Context?

Here is the code I am currently working on:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(int id, MapLocation maplocation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MapLocationCompany mapLocationCompany = new MapLocationCompany();
        mapLocationCompany = cs.getMapLocationCompany(id);
        mlcc.MapLocationCompanies.Where(c => c.id == id).FirstOrDefault().Add(maplocation);
        mlcc.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("MapLocations", "Company", new { id = id });
    }

    return View(maplocation);
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> 'CanFindLocation.Classes.MapLocationCompany' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'CanFindLocation.Classes.MapLocationCompany' could be found

How can I add an object to the list, knowing the id of the `MapLocationCompany`?

Comment: You never add anything to the context. You're just creating an object then saving the context.

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a `MapLocation` directly to the `MapLocationCompany` object here:

```
mlcc.MapLocationCompanies.Where(c => c.id == id).FirstOrDefault().Add(maplocation);
```

That is incorrect. You want to add it to the `MapLocationList` property of a `MapLocationCompany` object. This might make it clearer:

```
var company = mlcc.MapLocationCompanies.Where(c => c.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

if (company != null) {
    company.MapLocationList.Add(mapLocation);
}
```

Comment: The code above does add the maplocation to the list, and appears to save it, however, if I try and add another object to the list, the previous object is not there....

Comment: That sounds like a different problem altogether. Sounds like you have a list in the code but a one-to-one on the database side. I would expect an error though...